# How to retrieve Dynamics CRM 365 data asynchronous on server side

Tags: c#, async-await, dynamics-crm

I am implementing an Web API which retrieves data from several Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365, aggregates the data and returns it to the caller.

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the data from the CRM Organization Service asynchronously.
Neither the [CrmServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient?view=dynamics-xrmtooling-ce-9) nor the ServiceContext generated by the CrmSvcUtil offery async operations.
Is there no possibility to make async crm query calls?

Comment: If it's a simple REST or SOAP service, you can always build your own client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http requests to `Xrm.WebApi` are asynchronous by default, e.g. [Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/Xrm-WebApi/retrieveRecord). Examples in the API document I've linked there are written in JavaScript, but you can of course make Http requests to the WebApi from C# too.

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/samples/basic-operations-csharp) demonstrates basic CRUD operations to the WebApi using C# and `HttpClient.SendAsync()`. Extract:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connect"].ConnectionString;

using (HttpClient client = SampleHelpers.GetHttpClient(
   connectionString,
   SampleHelpers.clientId,
   SampleHelpers.redirectUrl,"v9.0"))
{
   Console.WriteLine("--Section 1 started--");
   string queryOptions;
   contact1.Add("firstname", "Rafel");
   contact1.Add("lastname", "Shillo");

   HttpRequestMessage createrequest1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
      client.BaseAddress + "contacts");
   createrequest1.Content = new StringContent(contact1.ToString());
   createrequest1.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

   HttpResponseMessage createResponse1 = client.SendAsync(createrequest1, 
   HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;

   if (createResponse1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Contact '{0} {1}' created.", contact1.GetValue("firstname"), contact1.GetValue("lastname"));
      contact1Uri = createResponse1.Headers.GetValues("OData-EntityId").FirstOrDefault();
      entityUris.Add(contact1Uri);
      Console.WriteLine("Contact URI: {0}", contact1Uri);
   }
}
```